# react-routers nested route not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm starter in React for a few weeks. and I try to make my own boilerplate. Today I install react-router and I have a problem. You can see my routes code down here.

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Menubar}>
        <IndexRoute component={App}/>
        <Route path="another" component={Another} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

When i open the web. its show me a Menubar components but not to show me App or Another components. How can I fix this problem

Thank you for help.

Comment: Please provide your Menubar component.

Comment: have you written `this.props.children` in render method of your Menubar component?

Comment: Wow! thank you @Vikramaditya It's work! I don't know this before.

Answer (score 0):

Nested Route concept:

IndexRouter: If you want a child route to be used as the default when no other child matches, you use a special route called . if my parent route was matched but none of my siblings matched, render me.

Nested Route:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={Menubar}>
    <IndexRoute component={App}/>
    <Route path="another" component={Another} />
</Route>
```

Components will be nested in accordance with how the router nests its routes. When the user visits the /, it will render Menubar and the default child App, when user visit another, it will render Menubar and Another.

{this.props.children}: All it means is **"render my child components here"**, inside the parent component.

History: React Router is built with history, a history knows how to listen to the browser's address bar for changes and parses the URL into a location object that the router can use to match routes and render the correct set of components.

browserHistory: creating real URLs that look like `example.com/some/path`

hashHistory: Hash history uses the hash (#) portion of the URL, creating routes that look like `example.com/#/some/path`,

Nice article on react router:

https://css-tricks.com/learning-react-router/

http://www.hackingwithreact.com/read/1/25/adding-a-root-route-using-react-router-and-indexroute